# Add a module as cron job

Tags: cron

I have a module file which fetch data from a link. I have to run this module as a cron everyday. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to run you task periodically on drupal cron.

```
function hook_cron() {
  // Your code here
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "your code"? will i write api calling function is where or what?

Comment: I mean what do you want to do with your module is write up there.

Comment: should i write hook_cron() in my module's .module file which i want to add in cron job?

Comment: You have written any function which fetches the data from api. Just call the function in `hook_cron()`. So whenever drupal cron will run, your function also will run.

Comment: where should i write the hook_cron()?

Comment: In you .module file. hook is the name of your module. So it should look something like `function mymodule_cron() {}`.